# Transpose results of a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to transpose this display.

```
SeqNo   Step        Date        By
1       Quoted      2018-03-01  Person1
2       Checked     2018-03-02  Person2
3       Authorized  2018-03-02  Person3
4       Approved    2018-03-03  Person4
```

Into this display.

```
1               2               3               4
Quoted          Checked         Authorized      Approved
2018-03-01      2018-03-02      2018-03-02      2018-03-03
Person1         Person2         Person3         Person4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use combination of **[unpivot and pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)** syntax to achieve your result and also end up casting everything in to same compatible datatype like varchar(max)

<kbd>**[live demo here](http://rextester.com/FQSVN43750)**</kbd>

See query below

```
create table srcTable (SeqNo int,  Step varchar(10), [Date] date,  [By] varchar(10));
insert into srcTable values
(1,'Quoted','2018-03-01','Person1')
,(2,'Checked','2018-03-02','Person2')
,(3,'Authorized','2018-03-02','Person3')
,(4,'Approved','2018-03-03','Person4')

select [1],[2],[3],[4] from
(
    select 
        SeqNo, 
        [c2]=cast(Step as varchar(max)) ,
        [c3]=cast([Date] as varchar(max)),
        [c4]=cast([By] as varchar(max))
    from 
         srcTable
    )s
unpivot
( 
    value for data in ([c2],[c3],[c4])
)up
pivot
(
    max(value) for SeqNo in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
   )p
```